# merge wordpress plugins

Tags: plugins, merging

```
codecanyon-577696-security-ninja
codecanyon-2927931-core-scanner-addon-for-security-ninja
codecanyon-3686330-scheduled-scanner-addon-for-security-ninja
codecanyon-8531381-events-logger-addon-for-security-ninja
```

All of four are in zip file so i want to create a single zip so whenever i install this single zip all four plugin will installed.

Now I want to merge them how to do this job

Answer (score 1):

Curiously WordPress *does* recognize multiple plugins in a directory, but results can be highly unstable. It also wouldn't be possible at all if plugins had overlapping file names inside.

I wouldn't recommend you attempt this by literally putting them together in a folder and going through installer.

You don't quite cover your situation in detail. The reasonable solutions I could thinkg of would be:

- uploading and extracting zip with the plugins directly
- using WP CLI command to install them quickly from remote URLs
- making a small plugin that will install these four (and possibly delete itself after)